# problem with function template parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Why does the following fail to compile?

```
inline Obj init_output_string() { return open_output_string(); }

template<typename... Args>
Obj init_output_string(Args... prev, int last)
{
    Obj port(init_output_string(prev...));
    write_char(port, last);
    return port;
}

int ch1 = ...;
int ch2 = ...;
Obj port = init_output_string(ch1, ch2);
```

(error is `'init_output_string': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments` for MSVC, g++ gives a similar error).

But the following variation does compile

```
inline Obj init_output_string() { return open_output_string(); }

template<typename... Args>
Obj init_output_string(int first, Args... rest)
{
    Obj port(init_output_string(rest...));
    write_char(port, first);
    return port;
}

int ch1 = ...;
int ch2 = ...;
Obj port = init_output_string(ch1, ch2);
```

The difference being the order in which the characters are written. I can work around this easily enough, but I'm curious to know what rule my first example is breaking.

Answer (score 1):

Your construction is illformed.
see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

> In a function template, the template parameter pack may appear earlier
>   in the list **provided that all following parameters can be deduced** from
>   the function arguments, or have default arguments:

the example given is(the latter in your case):

```
template<typename... Ts, typename U>
struct Invalid; // Error: Ts.. not at the end 

template<typename ...Ts, typename U, typename=void>
void valid(U, Ts...);  // OK: can deduce U

// void valid(Ts..., U); 
// Can't be used: Ts... is a non-deduced context in this position
```

the problem is "how to deduce where to stop the int fro the pack"? is your last int part of the pack or not?

Imagine the compiler is just going thru the list of parameters and should directly know where to stop the pack.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, in my example there are no following arguments to the template parameter pack (i.e. there's no equivalent of `typename U` from the examples you quote).

Comment: Well I tried replacing `int last` with `double last` and it made no difference. Forgetting about C++ for a minute there is no ambiguity, obviously given two actual parameters the parameter pack consumes the first and the normal parameter is the second, thats the only thing that fits. I'm still unsure what rules of C++ mean this doesn't work in practise.

Comment: Ok, I wonder if I don't get eventually your question; Is your question about the `init_output_string(prev...);` which doen't call the function with the first arguments? if so, remember that the full function name is init_output_string<Args...> in this case, thus it doesn't match any prototype...

Comment: I'm getting more and more confused. If `init_output_string(prev...);` in the first example doesn't match any prototype (not that I understand that either), why does `init_output_string(rest...);` in the second example compile?